# Is there any way to preview the command line Intellij generates for java run configurations?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, command-line-interface

Is there any way to preview the command line that intellij will generate and run when you add a run configuration for Java?

I'm running into issues where my command line is too long for windows to handle, but even after relocating and renaming a buch of files it still is too long. I would like to check the exact command line generated so I can find out the exact issues.

I have tried the built-in command line shortening, but this gives other issues in the project I'm working with.

Comment: A kind of `System.setOut` delegating to the original PrintStream and wrapping lines by a println.

Comment: I don't know answer to your question but I know one workaround. When you add Application run configuration there is field called "Shorten command line" at the bottom of the window. You can choose @argFiles and it will remove length limitation. But it works only for java 9+.

Comment: Too bad, I'm using Java 8. It's a big legacy project, so upgrading isn't an option.